# Custom back button on navigation bar Not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, back-button

I have used following code instead of showing the image I set inbuilt arrow image is shown

```
 //Set Back button on Navigation
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtn.png"]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtn.png"]];
```

Comment: refer this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6

Comment: I will check that out

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you..

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtn.png"]
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481559/swrevealviewcontroller-make-sidebar-button-static-make-the-rearview-appear-on-to any ideas ab this trouble

Comment: I have solved with same way as question i have posted thanks for effort .

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftButtonItem = [self barItemWithTitle:@"Back" xOffset:11 target:self action:nil];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButtonItem;
```

Below method returns `UIBarButtonItem` for Navigation Bar.

```
- (UIBarButtonItem*)barItemWithTitle:(NSString*)title xOffset:(NSInteger)xOffset target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
    [button addTarget:target action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    CGSize size = [title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f]}];
    CGSize adjustedSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(size.width), ceilf(size.height));
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0,adjustedSize.width + 3,24);
    [button setFrame:rect];
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        [button setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, xOffset, 0, -xOffset)];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *customUIBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    return customUIBarButtonItem;
}
```

Action Method

```
-(void)buttonAction{
     //Your code goes here.
}
```

May this help lot.

Comment: @nischalhada defiantly it's working because i am using this.

Comment: I have solved with same way as question i have posted thanks for effort .

Comment: Any ideas ab this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481559/swrevealviewcontroller-make-sidebar-button-static-make-the-rearview-appear-on-to