# SWRevealViewController make sidebar button static & make the rearView appear on top of the frontView

Tags: ios, storyboard, objective-c-blocks, swrevealviewcontroller

Is there any way to make the rearView appear on top of the frontView as below image in storyboard using Objective-C. I want to make the Front View navigation Fixed & make sidebar button static.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have solution for this kind of menu work

Comment: Your application is into only portrait mode only?

Comment: yes it is dude only portrait can u help me out

Answer (score 1):

This kind of android drawer external and open source library called as a `CCKFNavDrawer`.

[CCKFNavDrawer](https://github.com/calvinchankf/CCKFNavDrawer)

For using this following code.

```
self.rootNav = (CCKFNavDrawer *)self.navigationController;
[self.rootNav setCCKFNavDrawerDelegate:self];
```

Then implement delegate method

```
- (void)CCKFNavDrawerSelection:(NSInteger)selectionIndex
{
  NSLog(@"%i", selectionIndex);
}
```

May this helps lot.

Comment: I will check that out and will inform u